# UILabel and UITableViewCell background colours coming out different

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, colors, uilabel

I am trying to setup a general colour scheme for my app using code so it's easily modified when porting between projects. However, the two colours on these components keep coming out slightly different colours. I use the following code to setup my UITableViewCell:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    if ([indexPath row] %2 != 0)
    {
        [cell setBackgroundColor:kTableSecondaryCellColor];
    }
}
```

and this for my UILabel:

```
[self.lTitleBackground setBackgroundColor:kTableSecondaryCellColor];
```

As you can see I am simply setting the background on both of the elements to kTableSecondaryCellColor which is setup as follows:

```
#define kTableSecondaryCellColor [UIColor colorWithRed:(158.0f / 256.0f) green:(171.0f / 256.0f) blue:(4.0f / 256.0f) alpha:0.4f]
```

However, the results of the two colours come out as follows (green colour):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you try set up cell.contentView.backgroundColor = kTableSecondaryCellColor; I think it can cause the issue.

Comment: Perfect, this has been annoying me for days. Can you add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change background colour for content view of your cell:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = kTableSecondaryCellColor;
```

This should fix the issue.

Comment: Hi Greg, I was wondering if you can help me. This doesn't seem to be working for iPad, it still ignores the opacity element for some reason. Do you have any idea why this would be?

Comment: @ElliottD'Alvarez it should works for both. Are you sure you have exactly the same code?

Comment: @ElliottD'Alvarez if it's exactly the same code I don't know why is that maybe is worth to create another question.

Answer (score 2):

You must use

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = kTableSecondaryCellColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    if ([indexPath row] %2 == 0)
    {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = kColorTablePrimary;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = kColorTableSecondary;
    }
}
```

This is the code I am currently using, the opacity is only being detected on iPhone but I have a breakpoint in this code and it's definitely being called when I use the iPad just the opacity isn't showing. I've been through the setup and the cells are both setup identically, the same with the UITableViews.